# how to show text as much bigger size as like magnifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, label

I've an app with collection view, in that I'm displaying some text in  UILabel on collection view item. My text size is bigger than my label size due to that it was not able to see the text fully. So, I planned to display the text as bigger size when holds on it. Can someone please help me how can I achieve this. For reference please see screenshot.

[image]

In gmail when we mouse over the email attachment it will shows download and save to drive text same as like that when user holds on text it has to display that text clearly. Please see screenshot for refernce. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBh2b.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are attempting to do? It is my understanding you need to somehow magnify the text (or the whole cell?) to allow the user to read the full text. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Can you please see my edited question i mentioned clearly now. thanks @il3v

Comment: If the problem is with the text being truncated, you could add a uigesture (long tap or 3dtouch) that shows a bigger version of the cell, or just of the label. Just my two cents: the problem here, in my opinion, is more of user experience, because I would rather rethink the cell to show as much content as possible (maybe using a UITableView instead of a UICollectionView) than engage myself in something that allows the user to crawl between myriads of cells with truncated text before finding the file they're looking for. But again, this is just my opinion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [SwiftPopTipView](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwiftPopTipView) in the following way with your collection view's cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("did select cell \(indexPath.row)")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let popTip = SwiftPopTipView()
    popTip.animation = .Slide
    popTip.popColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    popTip.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x474747)
    popTip.dismissTapAnywhere = true
    popTip.message = "Test poptip" //***YOUR TEXT GOES HERE***
    popTip.presentAnimatedPointingAtView(cell!, inView: collectionView, autodismissAtTime: 1.5)
}
```

I hope it works for you. Happy coding!

Comment: what is the pod name for this like **pod 'xxxname of pod filexxxx'**

Comment: or else i need to add this class file in to my project

Comment: @Rahul It's provided as open source. No pods. So, you have to add this class to your project.